# Letters of Recommendation

Tags: job-search

Is it a good idea to include a letter of recommendation in addition to a resume when sending an email in response to a job opening?

Answer (score 2):

Adding a clause in your CV that says something like:

> "Letter of recommendation available on request."

is probably the best way to go.

Recruiters want to the most important things about you that can fit on a page or two, adding more files and data may overwhelm the recruiters.

Additional files are more appropriate as the recruiting process goes further and when you know that they're certainly interested in you, just mentioning that you have a letter of recommendation for those who are interested in seeing it in the first place is sufficient as a starting point.